# Is there a way to create hierarchical taxonomies checkboxes?

Tags: 8, forms, taxonomy-terms

I have an issue where I want to keep sub category inside a parent category. Say, for preferred vehicle I want a checkbox like this in node creation form

```
[]Car
  []Volkswagen
  []Toyota
[]Bike
  []Kawasaki
  []Harley Davidson
```

Is there a way to implement this using taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taxonomy is hierarchical by nature, you can create category/sub stuff in it.

AFAIK, there is not any field widget as you describe in drupal core with taxonomy field. Maybe some contrib module (have a look at [term_reference_fancytree](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_fancytree) ).

You also may define your own and generate a field widget dedicated to taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you, it does fulfill my use case